# how can i ask people to rate my game in Facebook and how can i extract the ratings information from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i searched in Facebook developers tutorial to find something about rating a my application ( a game) via itself, and to extract the ratings information about my app. didn't find something that can help. So if anyone have a solution please help me.
Thanks

Comment: We will randomly ask people that played your game to rate it. And we do that so the system is a lot harder to game

Comment: thanks for helping, i wanted to know how do i get the information about ratings ( user names of people that rated and the value of their rate ...)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/app/app_insights) of the `/{app-id}/app_insights` endpoint of the Graph API, this is not available to you.

If you want to know who rated your app with what score, implement your own rating mechanism that asks players for that information, however, this is out of scope of this question and answer.